# change excel cell color if date in cell mentioned is less than 20 days from date today

Tags: excel

i'm newbie in excel and i have an excel sheet where i need to change the cell color if the date mentioned in the cell is becomes 15 days old and also add a status in next column as pending.Please help with this.

Comment: Google "conditional formatting" (and also the `IF` function)

Answer (score 0):

This is the formula you might be looking for:

```
=IF(DAYS(TODAY(),A1)>=15,"pending",other_status_you_use)
```

Then you should go to

```
Conditional Formatting > Highlight Cell Rules > Text that Contains...
```

There you can type `pending` and change the color as you wish.

Comment: First part is not really relevant. Part that is relevant is Conditional Formatting

Comment: @boris thanks for the help,but this formula always checks the cell A1,i want it to be like it should always check the corresponding cell like if i'm entering a date in cell A2 which is 15 days greater than date today then B2 cell should display pending,it should not check cell A1.

Comment: Hi Rohit,
The formula I sent you should work perfectly and all you need to do is to drag it all the way down to the last data row.
For instructions on how to drag formula please visit [this link](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Copy-a-formula-by-dragging-the-fill-handle-in-Excel-2016-for-Mac-dd928259-622b-473f-9a33-83aa1a63e218)

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your dates are in ColumnA, please select that column and HOME > Styles - Conditional Formatting, New Rule..., *Use a formula to determine which cells to format* and **Format values where this formula is true:**:

```
=TODAY()-A1>=15
```

<kbd>Format...</kbd>, select your choice of colour for formatting, <kbd>OK</kbd>, <kbd>OK</kbd>.

If the "pending" labels re then to be added in ColumnB where appropriate please put in B1 and copy down to suit:

```
=IF(TODAY()-A5>=15,"pending","")
```

You could use the `pending` in ColumnB to trigger the colour for ColumnA but it may be better to keep the two requirements separate. If you were to trigger via 'pending' you would still need a formula rule, rather than a "cell content" one.

Change `15` to `20` when you have decided what the interval should be. Beware that if your ColumnA values include times (even if not displayed) you cannot reliably simplify `>=15` to `>14`.